# Is it possible to get paths to all apps with the defined bundle identifier

Tags: macos, cocoa, apple-documentation

I need to check if the app exist on system disk. And it works fine if I don't have connected external hard drive. But it also returns me the path to apps on external hard drive sometimes.

I use absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier method of NSWorkspace.

It is described in documentation. But I'm currently unable to find what I need.

[-NSWorkspace absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1533086-absolutepathforappbundlewithiden?language=objc)

[-NSWorkspace URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1534053-urlforapplicationwithbundleident?language=objc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 10.10, there's [`LSCopyApplicationURLsForBundleIdentifier()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1449290-lscopyapplicationurlsforbundleid?language=objc).